# c# Is it possible to make an Inherited Generic class be of two specified type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In c# I have problem, where I have A health manager that must be Inherited  by one of these two types  `StatusManager<PlayerStatusModel>` or `StatusManager<MobStatusModel>` but I dont know how to achieve that and for that I seek your help

```
public class StatusManager<T> : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected T model; // it must be of either Player or Mob model

    protected void Awake()
    {
        model = GetComponent<T>();
    }
}
```

the way I tried to do:

```
public class HealthManager<T> : StatusManager<T> where T : StatusManager<PlayerStatusModel>, StatusManager<MobStatusModel>
```

And since MobShould Only Have

Comment: Is there any commonality between `PlayerStatusModel` and `MobStatusModel`? Do they share a common base class, or interface?

Comment: well the oly thing they share In common would Be the hp, but the player has the weight status for example I also have a WeightManager that inherits from StatusManager so I think that this would cause an error or something

Comment: The best you can do is `where T : StatusModel` where `StatusModel` would be a common base type to `PlayerStatusModel` and `MobStatusModel` (and not `T : StatusManager<StatusModel>` or similar as you have tried to do).

Comment: You can only derive from (= extend) one class at a time